# Why's the red polygon goes out of plane, then returns to its specified place again?

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I want to put the red polygon in place of the empty one. But it goes above it first before returning again to it. Can someone help me with that?

Why's the red polygon goes out of plane, then returns to its specified place again?

[image]

```
def Rotating(Rotating_angle, polygon_points):  # Drawing the rotated figure
    my_points = (re.findall("\(\-?\d*\.?\d*\,\-?\d*\.?\d*\)", polygon_points))
    sleep_time = .5
    my_new_points = []  # Scale_points
    for point in my_points:
        new_point = str(point).replace(")", "").replace("(", "").split(",")

        # creating a list with all coordinates components
        all_coordinates_components = []
        all_coordinates_components.append(abs(eval(new_point[0])))
        all_coordinates_components.append(abs(eval(new_point[1])))

        point = (scale * eval(new_point[0]), scale * eval(new_point[1]))

        my_new_points.append(point)

        rotated_points = []

        for point in my_new_points:
            new_point = str(point).replace(")", "").replace("(", "").split(",")
            theta = Rotating_angle
            X = (eval(new_point[0]) * cos(theta * pi / 180)) - (eval(new_point[1]) * sin(theta * pi / 180))
            Y = (eval(new_point[0]) * sin(theta * pi / 180)) + (eval(new_point[1]) * cos(theta * pi / 180))

            # length = sqrt((X) ** 2 + (Y) ** 2)

            point = (X, Y)
            rotated_points.append(point)


    # draw steps
    time.sleep(sleep_time)

    draw_rotation_steps(my_new_points, theta)  # draw steps        ((((( 3 )))))

    # drawing rotated polygon
    draw_polygon(rotated_points)  # draw rotated polygon           ((((( 4 )))))

    s = Shape('compound')
    poly1 = (my_new_points)
    s.addcomponent(poly1, fill="red")
    register_shape('myshape', s)
    shape('myshape')

    polygon = Turtle(visible=False)
    polygon.setheading(90)
    polygon.speed('slowest')

    polygon.penup()
    polygon.shape('myshape')
    polygon.st()
    polygon.circle(0, theta)

    pen_dot = Turtle(visible=False)
    pen_dot.speed('fastest')
    for point in rotated_points:
        pen_dot.penup()
        pen_dot.goto(point)
        pen_dot.pendown()
        pen_dot.dot(5, 'blue violet')
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the behaviour you describe.  But your code is riddled with issues that should be addressed so perhaps fixing those might also fix the positioning issue:

These loops are nested, but they shouldn't be:

```
my_new_points = []
for point in my_points:
        ...
        rotated_points = []
        for point in my_new_points:
```

They both should be at the same level.

You shouldn't use `eval()`.  In this situation, use `float()`:

```
point = (scale * eval(new_point[0]), scale * eval(new_point[1]))
```

Here, you've already converted the points but you turn them back into strings and reconvert them:

```
new_point = str(point).replace(")", "").replace("(", "").split(",")

X = (eval(new_point[0]) * cos(theta * pi / 180)) - (eval(new_point[1]) * sin(theta * pi / 180))
```

when you can simply do:

```
X = point[0] * cos(theta * pi / 180) - point[1] * sin(theta * pi / 180)
```

You don't have to put the pen down for the `.dot()` method to work:

```
pen_dot.goto(point)
pen_dot.pendown()
pen_dot.dot(5, 'blue violet')
```

so you can move the `penup()` out of the loop.

Below is my rework of your example code.  I've added just enough code to make it runnable and removed anything that had nothing to do with the problem.  See if this gives you any ideas of how to simplify and fix your own code:

```
import re
from math import sin, cos, pi
from turtle import *

scale = 20

def draw_rotation_steps(points, theta):

    ''' Not supplied by OP '''

    pass

def draw_polygon(rotated_points):

    ''' Simple replacement since not supplied by OP '''

    hideturtle()
    penup()
    goto(rotated_points[-1])
    pendown()
    for point in rotated_points:
        goto(point)

def Rotating(theta, polygon_points):  # Drawing the rotated figure
    my_points = re.findall(r"\(\-?\d*\.?\d*\,\-?\d*\.?\d*\)", polygon_points)

    my_new_points = []  # Scaled points

    for point in my_points:
        X, Y = point.replace(")", "").replace("(", "").split(",")

        point = (scale * float(X), scale * float(Y))

        my_new_points.append(point)

    rotated_points = []

    for point in my_new_points:
        X = point[0] * cos(theta * pi / 180) - point[1] * sin(theta * pi / 180)
        Y = point[0] * sin(theta * pi / 180) + point[1] * cos(theta * pi / 180)

        point = (X, Y)
        rotated_points.append(point)

    # draw steps

    draw_rotation_steps(my_new_points, theta)  # draw steps

    # drawing rotated polygon
    draw_polygon(rotated_points)  # draw rotated polygon

    s = Shape('compound')
    s.addcomponent(my_new_points, fill="red")
    register_shape('myshape', s)

    polygon = Turtle('myshape', visible=False)
    polygon.setheading(90)
    polygon.showturtle()

    polygon.circle(0, theta, steps=100)  # added steps to visually slow it down

    pen_dot = Turtle(visible=False)
    pen_dot.penup()

    for point in rotated_points:
        pen_dot.goto(point)
        pen_dot.dot(5, 'blue violet')

Rotating(180, "(-8,-6) (-6,-3) (-3,-4)")

mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much; this helped a lot. Can we further flip this polygon or mirror it?